# I getting the following error using Dagger 2, Retrofit2 and AndroidAnnotations

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, dagger-2, android-annotations

i'm creating a MVP(Model View Presenter) project using Dagger 2(DI), Retrofit2  and AndroidAnnotations. But when injecting this component inside the main function in Activity.class:

```
((App) getApplication()).getNetComponent().inject(this);
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable 
@Provides method
```

find below attached my code:
MainActivity.java:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main_view)
public class MainViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SampleMainView {

  @Inject
  SampleMainPresenter sampleMainPresenter;

  @AfterViews
  void setupView(){
    ((App) getApplication()).getNetComponent().inject(this);
  }

}
```

App.java:

```
public class App extends Application {
  private NetComponent mNetComponent;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mNetComponent = DaggerNetComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .netModule(new NetModule("http://www.bancaderiesgo.com/proyectos_admon/clases/"))
            .sampleMainPresenterModule(new SampleMainPresenterModule())
            .build();

  }

  public NetComponent getNetComponent() {
    return mNetComponent;
  }

}
```

AppModule.java:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

  Application mApplication;

  public AppModule(Application application){
    this.mApplication = application;
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  Application provideApplication(){
    return mApplication;
  }

}
```

NetModule.java:

```
 @Module
 public class NetModule {

  String mBaseUrl;

  public NetModule(String BaseUrl){
    this.mBaseUrl = BaseUrl;
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  Cache provideHttpCache(Application application){
    int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    Cache cache = new Cache(application.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
    return  cache;
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  Gson provideGson(){
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(
         FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    return gsonBuilder.create();
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(Cache cache){
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.cache(cache);
    return client.build();
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient){
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
  }

}
```

SampleMainPresenterModule.class

```
   @Module
   public class SampleMainPresenterModule {

      SampleMainView view;
      SampleMainInteractor sampleMainInteractor;

      @Provides
      @Singleton
      SampleMainView providesSampleMainView(){
        return view;
      }

      @Provides
      @Singleton
      SampleMainInteractor providesSampleInteractor(){
        return sampleMainInteractor;
      }

    }
```

SampleMainView.class

```
    public interface SampleMainView {

       void showMessage(String message);

       void showError(String error);

       void result(String msg);

   }
```

SampleMainInteractor.java

```
   public interface SampleMainInteractor {

      interface LoadListener {
        void onLoaded(List<String> items);
      }

      void loadItems(LoadListener listener);

    }
```

Does anyone know how to solve this error?
Thanks!

Comment: It's exactly what the error states, one of your `@Provides` annotated methods returns `null`. You did not include the stacktrace, so we have no idea about where or why.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak sorry, i missed this bit of code 'SampleMainPresenterModule.class'

Comment: Now you should have a look at that class. Is `view` `null`, or are you initializing it somewhere? What about `sampleMainInteractor`? Are you assigning a value to either one somewhere?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak i edit my code and add another snipets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `MainPresenterModule`:

```
@Module
public class SampleMainPresenterModule {

   SampleMainView view;
   SampleMainInteractor sampleMainInteractor;

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   SampleMainView providesSampleMainView(){
     return view; //null pointer here
   }

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   SampleMainInteractor providesSampleInteractor(){
     return sampleMainInteractor; //null pointer here
   }
}
```

Think about what happens when Dagger 2 tries to wire up your dependency graph in this case. You are saying "`SampleMainView` should be provided from the `view` field in this module" yet the the `view` field is never initialised.

Modules for Presenters normally need constructors in which to pass in the View. Something like this:

```
@Module
public class SampleMainPresenterModule {

   SampleMainView view;
   SampleMainInteractor sampleMainInteractor;

   SampleMainPresenterModule(SampleMainView view, SampleMainInteractor interactor) {
       this.view = view;
       this.interactor = interactor;
   }

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   SampleMainView providesSampleMainView(){
     return view; 
   }

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   SampleMainInteractor providesSampleInteractor(){
     return sampleMainInteractor;
   }
}
```

Then there is the problem of where to initialise the `MainPresenterModule`. You are currently initialising it inside your Application subclass.

This is probably not the right approach - you want to use a subcomponent or a dependent component and configure the component with the presenter module inside your Activity or Fragment. The tutorial or book you are following should explain this.

If you were using dependent components (I think these are easier to start with) then you would do something like this in your Activity:

```
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   DaggerMainComponent.builder()
       .netComponent(((App)getApplication())
       .mainPresenterModule(new SampleMainPresenterModule(this, this))
       .build() 
       .inject(this);
```

Comment: Hi!, thanks so much, it worked. You know how to call Retrofit 2 for the data source?